# Incorrect difference between two dates in RoR 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

RoR 4.0.3 / Postgres 9.1.12

When I execute following query in `PgAdmin`

```
SELECT extract('epoch' from expires_at) - extract('epoch' from now()) as secs_left 
FROM "auctions" ORDER BY "auctions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

I get correct value of seconds between `expires_at` (it's type is `DATETIME`)  and current time (positive when `expires_at > now()` and negative otherwise).
But when I execute query from rails, I always get positive value that is much bigger that correct value

```
@auction = Auction.select("extract('epoch' from expires_at) - extract('epoch' from now()) as secs_left").first
logger.debug @auction.secs_left
```

In console I see

```
Auction Load (0.7ms)  SELECT *, extract('epoch' from expires_at) - extract('epoch' from now()) as secs_left FROM "auctions" ORDER BY "auctions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
5472.91183400154
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Hint on StackOverflow: use ctrl+k to format text into code, the backquotes caracters are meant for inline-code, like this `part` in a sentence.

Comment: Share the logger.debug output and the PgAdmin output.

Comment: logger.debug's output is pasted above - 5472.91183400154. Executing of query in PgAdmin just returns actual value of seconds between expires_at and now(). And it was much lesser that 5472.91183400154